# How do we see the logs (from Logger instances) in production forGoogle Dataflow?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

I have a ParDo function that works when running over 100K instances but fails when I try to run over billion records. At that point, I can't run using DirectPipelineRunner and have to switch to DataflowPipelineRunner or BlockingDataflowPipelineRunner. I have a logger instantiated as below in my DoFn:

```
private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(EventPipeline.class);
```

However, I don't see output of `LOG.error('...')` in the cloud logs when I click `View Logs` button next to my job. I even switched to `worker` and log-level to `any log level` in the options.

Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 1):

To make sure I understand the context of your question: you have just started using `[Blocking]DataflowPipelineRunner`, and are trying to figure out how to debug your job now that you can't see logging output locally/use your other local debugging tools.

For the logs question - it doesn't sound like you're missing anything obvious. Based on your description, cloud logging should work correctly.

Here's what I'd suggest for next steps:

1. Make sure that the logging statements are working correctly - when you test it with DirectPipelineRunner (with a smaller # of records), I presume you are seeing the log statements show up then. If that's the case, they should definitely be showing up in Cloud Logs. You can also put a log statement in an earlier DoFn (or just earlier inside of the DoFn code.)
2. Make sure that Dataflow -> Cloud Logging communication is working for your job. Do you see any log lines in the `worker` logs at all, or just not your particular error log line? If you are seeing other log lines in the `worker` log, it most likely means that the line where the logging statement is being emitted isn't getting run.

As a last resort you can try replacing the log.error, throwing a regular java exception instead. That would fail the step and the errors would show up in the dataflow monitoring UI. That would prove that the line where the logging statement is was getting run, but that cloud logging wasn't receiving the logging data.

Comment: What should one do if logging isn't working at all? I see worker logs, but they none of the log lines come directly from my pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

I've experienced the same problem as well.

What I did was during the job execution, clicked on View logs --> Live Stream Logs (Play Button). It streams all the logs. In those logs, our job logs are also present. But its with the whole bunch of other logs. Its really hard to find our logs. I think we don't have other options.

Selecting the workers or changing the log levels didn't helped or me either.

Comment: Sorry to hear that the log filtering view didn't work for you. We've recently fixed several bugs in the Cloud Logging UI that should make the log name filters & job filters work correctly when opened via the View Logs link. Live Stream Logs will play nicely with those filters and just show you the `worker` logs for your job (which should contain very little besides the log lines you emit in your code.)

Comment: @DavorBonaci - Thanks for updating me. I will look into the logs when I run the dataflow job next time

Answer (score 0):

Just because I also just ran into the issue: Have you checked your classpath?

Doublecheck that there is no `Log4j` and/or `slf4j-log4j` binding on the classpath.
The Cloud logging is based on SLF4j but having log4j screws up the logging. If so exclude it from inclusion and just provide `log4j-over-slf4j`:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>log4j-over-slf4j</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>some</groupId>
  <artifactId>dependency</artifactId>
  <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
      <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    </exclusion>
    <!-- and / or depending on the upstream pom.xml -->
    <exclusion>
      <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
      <groupId>log4j</groupId>
    </exclusion>
  </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Having commons-logging on the classpath is fine (third party dependencies may use it). Just ensure that it doesn't use log4j as binding.

Answer (score 0):

If you still can see the dataflow worker logs from stack driver console. The problem is we need correct dependency for the project which is two following dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-jdk14</artifactId>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
    <optional>true</optional>
</dependency>
```

Also make sure that no other logging libs like log4j, logback, etc. are included.